# Enrich case class via implicit extension

Tags: scala, shapeless

there is `Person` model `case class` which is exposed to the client via REST endpoint.

```
scala> case class Person(firstname: String, lastname: String)
defined class Person
```

Now one of the internal service wants to "enrich" this `Person case class` and add social security number to it. BUT that enrichment is only to populate social security number from one service and pass it along to another one.

Immediate thought is to add `ssn` property to `Person` as follow - but that's not desired given `Person` is exposed to endpoint consumer and SSN MUST NOT be visible to any user calling REST endpoint which exposes `Person` data.

```
case class Person(firstname: String, lastname: String, ssn: String)
```

So another thought is to enrich `Person` case class as follow

```
scala> implicit class ExtendedPerson(person: Person){
 | val SSN : String = ""
 | }
defined class ExtendedPerson
```

then `Service1.findPerson` API will have `implicit` in the scope and will want to prepare `Person` as follow

```
val person = Person(firstName="Joe",lastname="Doe", ssn ="123-456-0000")
```

and then

```
Service2.moreWorkWithPerson(person,other arguments)
```

then `Service2.moreWorkWithPerson` will want to get `ssn=123-456-0000` from `person` argument.

what's the right way to achieve this in Scala without modifying definition of `Person case class`? Can shapeless help? any pointers would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

SSN as val in ExtendedPerson makes not much sense, instead it should be a function which queries your DB using the persons first and lastname. Given the fact that your DB is slow and you might call Person.SSN more than once I would suggest not to use this pattern as it will query your DB everytime you call .SSN. Instead I would write an implicit converter for Person to convert more explicitly.

```
case class ExtendedPerson(basicInfo: Person,ssn: String)

implicit class PersonHelper(person: Person) extends AnyVal{
 def extended = {
   val ssn = DB.querySSN(...)
   ExtendedPerson(person,ssn)
 }
}


val person: ExtendedPerson = Person("John","Doe").extended

//person = ExtendedPerson(Person("John","Doe"),"123-456-0000"")
```

Note: The code is written out of mind but should be logically correct

Comment: Is there any reason to use an `implicit class` rather than an `implicit def`? Also, why not `extends AnyVal`?

Comment: My answer would have been similar to this, so +1 from me. I'd suggest having both a `def withSSN(ssn: String)` and a `def withSSN()` - the first lets a developer explicitly pass a SSN, the second loads from the DB as in shim_'s answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are overthinking this. What's wrong with this?

```
case class Person(firstname: String, lastname: String, ssn: Option[String] = None);
```

Now, in REST handler you do `return Person("John", "Doe")`, and in the other service: `return Person("John", "Doe", Some("111-11-1111"))`

Comment: that was the first choice which I am trying to avoid for these reasons. adding Option with default None for sensitive data like SSN - leaves responsibility on developer to pick and choose what members to expose to client - creating a risk of exposing SSN. also it'll be quite tedious to `return Person("John", "Doe") etc - as real life case class has numerous parameters so it can get cumbersome to choose parameters at the time of return.

Comment: @user2066049 I don't see how knowing to instantiate the right class (or import the right implicit)  is less "responsibility on developer", than knowing to call the right constructor instance. One would still need to take steps to obtain the actual SSN value either way, which is unlikely to happen by accident. As to the second point, by `return Person("John", "Doe")` I just mean that your REST controller would continue doing the same thing it does now. Whether it is cumbersome or not is orthogonal to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just expose a different class to the client.

```
case class Person(firstname: String, lastname: String, ssn: String) {
  def toClient = ClientPerson(firstname, lastname)
}

case class ClientPerson(firstname: String, lastname: String)

object RESTService {
  def getPerson(id: String): ClientPerson = {
    val p: Person = DB.getPerson(id)
    p.toClient
  }
}
```